# How can I use a ttf file for a button's text?

Tags: android

How can I use a ttf file for a button's text?

Answer (score 5):

Does it mean you have to change fonts of the button?

```
Context context = textView.getContext();
    helvetica_normal = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/helvetica.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(helvetica_normal);
```

This is the code to change the font of text view to android default to helvetica.
As Button extends Text view, you can directly use this code without any modification, for button, text view and if I m not wrong spinner too.

**Note** : Its assumed that you have copied a ttf file of font to your assests folder.

Answer (score 1):

a handy and easy routine for applying this across a whole actvity, is to call the following after setContentView() in onCreate().  also useful in Adapter.getView()

```
static Typeface typeface = null;
static void ApplyOurFont(Context context,ViewGroup vg)
{
    if (typeface==null)
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"ourfont.ttf");
    int cnt = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0;i<cnt;++i)
    {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)v;
            tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            ApplyOurFont(context,(ViewGroup)v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Prahams Post i just used the code snippet inside my class. I just created two methods which do all the work, so you have just to pass each element to the method and it will be created in the specific ttf-font.

I created a variable at the beginning of my Class

```
Typeface typeface;
```

then you have to pass the instantiated elements to the method

```
setFont(anyElement);
```

and here the two methods which do the work. inside "setFont" the second method "getFontFromAsset" will be called, so the font can be changed at one position if needed.

```
private void setFont(TextView element){
    Context context = element.getContext();     
    element.setTypeface(getFontFromAsset(context));     
}

private Typeface getFontFromAsset(Context context){     
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "beware.ttf");
    return typeface;
}
```

---

or to make it more usefull, source it out to a new class. than there is just one place where to set the font, and you just have to init this class in your activities and pass the elements through the FontClass methods.

Here my FontClass

```
package xandru.cea;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontClass {

    Typeface typeface;

    public FontClass(){

    return;     
    }

    public void setFont(TextView element){
    Context context = element.getContext();     
        element.setTypeface(getFontFromAsset(context));     
    }

    private Typeface getFontFromAsset(Context context){     
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "beware.ttf");
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

than init the class:

```
FontClass fontClass = new FontClass();
```

and pass elements through:

```
fontClass.setFont(anyElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example here: http://androideity.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/fuentes14.png

Just change customFont to your button.